# HTML5 navigation, structure and semantics

Tags: css, html, menu, navigation, structure

I've been asking a lot of questions lately, but hopefully this will be the last one for a while.

I've put up an example at: http://myhideout.eu/menu/

Basically it's all about the menu for my new site, the structural design which is a bit different than what you usually see, semantics and all such thing

Basically it consist of a number of tabs, which are not actual links, though they could be.
Below is a predefined area which will serve one of two purposes.

Assuming that the use is not browsing the menu, the area will be used for something not related to navigation. For example displaying a banner image. Defined as main content.
When the menu is in use, this main content will not be displayed. The area will instead be used for the sub menus.

I should think that is simple enough, and assuming there's no serious browser compatibility issues with newer browsers, which at this time do not include ie8 and older. I may chose to support ie8, all in good time, b8ut in reality that will be more about supporting windows xp.

Now that is all well an good, and it works, but there are some questions that I'd like answered and some issue I should like solved.

First of all, if I can avoid using divs, I'd like to. If there's another element that is more suited, please let me know.

Secondly, it quickly gets confusing with all the :hover and what not. The CSS as it is, is a mess, and all suggestions will be most welcome.

Thirdly I've found, regarding the defined width of the li elements displayed as table-cells, that they act rather weird. If I set a width of 100%, the first cell will be made as wide as possible, while still displaying the others, but if I set an absolute pixel value that is too high, it all lines up perfectly. This is actually rather nice I think, which is why the width is currently set equal to the width of the navigation area, but is this a good approach and can I expect it to work in other never browsers, also in the future? Or is it better to just calculate the appropriate width?

Lastly, the main div, which is shown while the navigation isn't used, is not actually related to the navigation, but I haven't figured out how to do it without placing that element in the  element. Comments on this will also be appreciated.

There are probably issues which I haven't noticed or questions I've forgotten to pose, so again, any comments are very welcome.

I do hope to get some hight quality feedback here, and I expect I will ;)

So that's it for now.

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Edit:
Taking some of your advice and thinking a bit, I've altered the structure a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/hJuym/39/

I still haven't found a better alternative to display: table-cell
No matter what I end up with weird margins/paddings or untidy borders.

EDIT2:
I have now tried everything I can imagine, but am still unable to fix one tiny bitty problem.

I'm told that the table-cell attribute is a no go. While that is all well and good, it actually works EXACTLY as I want it too now, using the table-cell display attribute.

since table-cell is bad, apparently, I've tried to make it work with inline, which result in an odd top 1.5px padding or margin, which I can't get rid of, but more importantly, I'm unable to set a width on the li elements. Also the border are very hard to manage if you want them to look perfect. where as table-cell simply tread the border between two cells as one, apparently.

Then of course I've tried inline-block, which have had the most succes, though I'm forced to to remove certain spaces and line breaks in the html, which is annoying, but still I am unable to set a fixed width, though apparently I should be able to, and still the border are a mess.

Of course I've tried messing around with floats to, but that just gives me a headache. So I want 10 tabs. fine, just take the total width and divide by 10. Ya it works, unless you're unable to set width or want to use borders... jabba jabba jabba nit pick.

I'm not angry or anything, but I am confused, tired and giving up.

Please tell me why I can't just use what actually works, mainly the table-cell attribute, and assuming that there is a good reason, please do explain to me, in detail, what the alternative is, because I don't see it.l

example of newest working draft in last edit.

Best regards.

Comment: This, to me, seems like a VERY open ended set of questions. Can you be more specific about what you are trying to figure out?

Comment: To answer the question inside your navigation tab...div is short for division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Div, as mentioned. means "division". It's perfect for many scenarios and needn't be replaced except as mentioned by colinross in his answer. If you just need to group some markup in a convenient placeholder, don't be afraid to use `div`
2. I've tried to clean up your code a bit. See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hJuym/35/. Obviously there's some arbitrary measurements (like the width, height, and various offsets) but that wouldn't be difficult to change.
3. Don't use `table-cell` for display. Use block, inline, or inline-block, as colinross mentioned.
4. As shown in my jsfiddle above (http://jsfiddle.net/hJuym/35/), you don't have to. Wrap everything in a header, then split the header up into navigation and normal display content. The code explains itself.

EDIT: I added some explanatory comments to the fiddle above. For the commented version, see: http://jsfiddle.net/hJuym/36/

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I'll be sure to evaluate it carefully and get back with further comments. I would like to say though, that the reason I did use display:inline, is because it results in some weird 1.5px top margin or padding and I didn't wanna use float. Regarding block and inline block, I'll have to investigate further.

Comment: @Zacariaz for the record, if you use `inline-block`, it will convert white-space into spacing. so where `<element>` is `inline-block`, make sure you've got: `<element/><element/>` instead of `<element/> <element/>`

Comment: one important note before I go to bed. I'm interested in the #otherstuff, not being displayed all together, not just being covered, as it is my understanding is how it's done in the example. There are multiple reasons for this, but mainly it will seriously complicate certain aspects of styling. For now, thanks and good night.

Comment: You have bigger accessibility concerns there than your use of 'semantic' markup. Firstly, it's text-level semantics which is more important than block-level anyway (unless you know of someone, anywhere, who currently uses eg outlining). If you're worried about future-proof semantics, HTML is too lean a language to provide long-term *semantic* archiving of content (look at DocBook/DITA/etc for that). Think about the present, and get that navigation working for iPhone users without mouses and users working with their keyboard.

Comment: @Nicholas good point. I was just trying to take OP's original idea and run with it. But then, you could always display an entirely different page for mobile browsers anyways.

Comment: Well, not if he's keen on semantic markup! That's meant to be one of the selling points. ‘Content-driven, so just serve a different stylesheet’. I'm in the semantic camp myself, but `<header>`, `<nav>` etc is mostly snake-oil, not real concern for data storage and manipulation.

Comment: On a positive note, I like your use of display:table-cell. It's entirely appropriate, and if you're not targeting IE7, then it's doubly easy to go for it. It's a great way to make layouts which positively require JS otherwise (like on my homepage).

Comment: @Nicholas ...wait, i *didn't* use display:table-cell. Did you mean inline-block?

Comment: Sorry; it looked like a fragment, so I wasn't sure where you were using it. Interpret that as, "I like it that someone is using `display: table-cell`, and two people have already said it's bad, so I'll just add that it can be good". If you do ever have somewhere you need it, it's helpful (most likely, vertical alignment or horizontally filling space without float).

Answer (score 2):

In particular, the html 5 spec defined a few 'standout' new elements which I believe you are referencing here.

`<header>` (and `<footer>`), `<nav>`, and `<article>`, etc. are all just semantic containers if you will. 
Some, semantically, can be nested, like a `<nav>` element inside an `<article>` for article-level navigation (like jump to footnote).

The thing to remember is that they are inherently-linked to their parent elements, therefore

```
<body>
<header>Hi there!</header>
<nav>This would be site-level navigation</nav>
<article>
<header>Welcome to *this page*</header>
<nav>This would be page-level navigation</nav>
<p> Here is the actual page content </p>
</article>
```

You can imagine this code representing, semantically, that the site is saying "Hi There!", where as the page is saying "Welcome to this page".

Please be more specific for a better example/explanation.

Quick notes: don't define non-*table-cells* to be display: table-cell unless you want really weird behavior across browsers. Stick to display: {none, block, inline, inline-block}

Div stands for **div**ision

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm not as confused about the general concept of html5 semantics as one might think. Basically I have done the rest of the site, and there's only the header/navigation left, which in this case really is one and the same. I realise I've made an error regarding the table-cell, but as explained in the comment on the first reply, I had reasons, albeit maybe not very good reasons, to do so ;)

Comment: I've lately become a fan of `display:table-cell;` and friends -- largely for the benefits of `vertical-align`. What's the issue? It seems to work very nicely on all browsers -- except IE7, which doesn't understand it. The answer for me has been to feed an extra stylesheet for IE7, which overrides the main CSS and switches `display:table`-based layouts for uglier-but-function float-based alternatives, or sometimes faux columns.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to my previous answer, when push comes to shove, the new elements introduced are, in general, purely for semantics.  The W3C (Working Group) identified that a vast majority of websites were using divs to separate out their headers, footers, and navigation blocks. They added the elements in an effort to give consistency to websites so that browsers and other rendering engines, such as ARIA-compatable screen readers, and/or pragmatically developed parsers (like web crawlers) would be able to determine the semantic nature of the elements more consistently (like ignoring `body header` and `body navigation` elements and starting to read the page aloud to the user at the first `<article>` element.

Hope that helps